# Is it recommendable to use placement new when constructing an POD-object from a dynamically created array?

Tags: c++, placement-new

Given any POD type, is it recommendable to do something like that:

```
any_pod* p = new any_pod[n];
for (std::size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    new (&p[i].member) other_pod(whatever);
```

Comment: Why would you not just do `p[i].member = whatever;`? Keep it simple, there is no point in puzzling everyone with some obscure construct that offers no advantage.

Comment: You're re-constructing an already constructed object, which seems a bad habit to get into (even if probably harmless for a POD).

Comment: Working? Perhaps. Recommendable? NO!

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas - Because `member` is a struct with it's own constructor.

Comment: @FrEEzE2046: if it contains an object with a non-trivial constructor, then _it is not a POD_!  Therefore, what you have there is undefined behavior, since `new` constructs the objects, and then you construct again in the same memory location.

Comment: Whether or not the code is correct depends on the details, but it is definitely an ugly, horrible beast of code. The danger is that it totally obscures the intentions. If you want a class that dynamically manages some object in some private memory, you should design that cleanly. It's certainly possible. Post more details if you want specifics.

Comment: @KerrekSB: I don't think that it does depend on the objects, it is UB regardless of how bad the UB will manifest. That is, if the `member` has a constructor it has already been called, *reconstructing* on top of it is UB. Whether that itself means that the system will crash or just rewrite some values in memory and cause no harm falls withing the boundaries of what UB implies

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: `member` could be `char[1000]` or something innocuous like that... wouldn't that be fine? In fact, placement-constructing on char arrays is fairly common fare.

Comment: @KerrekSB An array does not *have it's own constructor*, which is the premise for UB (the fourth comment has that bit of information). If the object *has* a constructor, then it is UB. Whether in the particular case is innocuous or not is a different thing (i.e. if `member` is a class with constructor but with just a POD type stored internally, no virtual methods or virtual base classes and that also applies to it's own base classes, then you might get away with it, but it is still incorrect)

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: No disagreement, but I don't see how that's related. We don't have any details. So if `member` is a non-trivial object, then we have UB. But if `member` is a char array, then the code could be fine. That's why I said "it depends on the details". We don't know that `member` and `whatever` are of the same type, do we?

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas:  Constructing a new object atop an old object without calling the destructor of the old object does not yield undefined behavior.  See §3.8/4 which states, "for an object of a class type with a non-trivial destructor, the program is not required to call the destructor explicitly before the storage which the object occupies is reused or released." Of course, if you do this, "any program that depends on the side effects produced by the destructor has undefined behavior." [also from §3.8/4]

Comment: [I am not arguing that it is a good idea to do this, only that the behavior is not automatically undefined.]

Answer (score 1):

Given that the question is slightly subjective, no I would never recommend code like that. Regardless of whether it's undefined behavior or not, it's *still* hard to read and will require any future maintainers to take extra time (perhaps significant) to grok what you're doing.

If you need variable type capability either use `boost::variant` or `boost::any` depending on your needs.

If you just want to take the data from one class and copy/assign it to another, that's what converting constructors and converting assignment operators are for.

Answer (score 0):

By constructing on top of an already constructed object, you're violating the language's guarantees about destruction, so I would not do this, regardless of whether the object is a POD.

I wonder if you were trying to ask about something slightly different:

```
any_pod* p = reinterpret_cast<any_pod*>(malloc(n * sizeof(any_pod[n]));
for (std::size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i)
  new (&p[i].member) other_pod(whatever);
```

In this case, you're not reconstructing, you're simply constructing in a block of raw memory.  In this case, the placement new is appropriate.  (Though it's pretty rare that you'd have to write code like this.  It's the type of thing you might do when implementing something like std::vector.)  You have to be very careful to free the array later once the last pod has been destructed.

Comment: You can also use the standard `uninitialized_fill` or `uninitialized_copy` algorithms (in `<memory>`) for this sort of thing.